# Azure - get_blob_client - blob creation

Tags: azure, data-science, azure-blob-storage

Whats the exact functionality of `get_blob_client()`?

```
get_blob_client(container, blob, snapshot=None)
```

I understood as, it automatically creates one if its the blob is not yet available.

My issue :

I used `get_blob_client(container, blob, snapshot=None)` for creating NEW blobs before. It now neither shows error nor the blob is created.
Note: When tried `download_blob()` it say

> NO blob found.

Whats the issue here?

Comment: The documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#get-blob-client-blob--snapshot-none- explains that it's used for creating a client, which you can then use to interact with a blob

Comment: Please learn to format your questions properly

Comment: Sure . I will format better in future. Can you pls answer a solution for My issue in there?

Comment: Hi @Adrianibar , If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Workaround on the `get_blob_client()` function. It wont creates the blob it only creates the reference .

I tried with the python taken the sample example .I don’t have the example.txt blob in container (test) .When I **`call get_blob_client() function it creates the reference not the blob.`**

[image]

In azure storage the blob not created

[image]

So when you try to download the blob it throws the error. So Create the blob the get the reference for the blob then download it

[image]